# how to disable jetpack for non admins?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

I am using wordpress 4.2.3 and jetpack latest version. All users of my site are contributors. I want to hide jetpack from contributors. I hide the jetpack menu from dashboard by **WP admin UI customize** plugin. But when any user type url: **mysite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack** it is appearing on browser.I used this code,but not helped me.

```
function ap_remove_jetpack_page( ) {
    if ( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'jetpack' );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ap_remove_jetpack_page', 999 );
```

Escape me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code given below, In this code we are checking if page is 'jetpack' and based on that showing custom error message.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_page' );
function restrict_page() {
    if ( class_exists( 'Jetpack' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) && $_GET['page'] == 'jetpack' ) {
            wp_die( 'no access' );
        }
    }
}
```